# Why Spring greaterThan isn't working while the method should be used when using url without the max parameter?

Tags: spring

I request the data from my database. But for one or another reason the `findByCapacityGreaterThan` does not work. Although I think if I click on the `L` (large) it should use the `findByCapacityGreaterThan` method because there is no max paramter included.

```
public interface VenueRepository extends CrudRepository<Venue, Integer>{
    Iterable <Venue> findByCapacityBetween(Integer min, Integer max);
    Iterable <Venue> findByCapacityGreaterThan(Integer min);
}
```

```
@GetMapping(value = "/venuelist", params = {"min", "max"})
public String venueSize(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer min, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer max) {

        Iterable<Venue> venues = venueRepository.findByCapacityBetween(min, max);
        model.addAttribute("venues", venues);
        model.addAttribute("max", max);
        model.addAttribute("min", min);
        model.addAttribute("venuesActive", true);
        return "venues";
    }

@GetMapping(value = "/venuelist", params = {"min"})
public String venueSizeL(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer min) {
        Iterable<Venue> venues = venueRepository.findByCapacityGreaterThan(min);
        model.addAttribute("venuesL", venues);
        model.addAttribute("min", min);
        model.addAttribute("venuesActive", true);
        return "venues";
    }
```

```
<a th:href="@{/venuelist}" th:classappend="${max == null && min == null} ? 'active' : ''">all</a>
<a th:href="@{/venuelist?min=0&max=200}" th:classappend="${max == 200 && min == 0} ? 'active' : ''">S</a>
<a th:href="@{/venuelist?min=200&max=600}" th:classappend="${max == 600 && min == 200} ? 'active' : ''">M</a>
<a th:href="@{/venuelist?min=600}" th:classappend="${min == 600} ? 'active' : ''">L</a>
```

I also tried putting both methods together but that also doesn't work

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/venuelist", params = {"min", "max"})
    public String venueSize(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer min, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer max) {

        if (max == null) {
            Iterable<Venue> venues = venueRepository.findByCapacityGreaterThan(min);
            model.addAttribute("venuesL", venues);
            model.addAttribute("min", min);
            model.addAttribute("venuesActive", true);
        } else {
            Iterable<Venue> venues = venueRepository.findByCapacityBetween(min, max);
            model.addAttribute("venues", venues);
            model.addAttribute("max", max);
            model.addAttribute("min", min);
            model.addAttribute("venuesActive", true);
        }
        return "venues";
    }
```

Comment: Since your first method runs for between, aren't both parameters supposed to be set as `required = true` ? Or you can do both method in one. Check max first, if null run greaterThan, if not run between.

Comment: @Batu.Khan, yes I tried placing it in one methode together already (changed it in my code above so you can see). and putting on `required = true` also doesn't work...

Comment: when calling `/venuelist?min=600`, did you check what is min and max for the version "putting both methods together"?

Comment: @samabcde yeah I did... But I just found out what was wrong. When `max==null`  Iadded `venuesL` to the model in stead of `venues`... So that's why I got an error